# Using selenium CSS selector for multiple things

Tags: css, xpath, selenium, css-selectors

This is in Perl if it matters. I have several lists of links that collapse and expand. I know how many there are from using

`get_xpath_count('//li/a')`

The problem is I need to get a list of the names of these actual links. I've tried using xpath, but haven't found much luck, and was hoping CSS selectors would be able to help. I've tried using

`get_text('css=li a:nth-child('.$i.')'`

which prints out a [-] icon next to a link, the very top link in the list, and then an out of range error. I'm not familiar was CSS selectors at all, so any help would be great. If I left out important info, please let me know,

Answer (score 2):

Try this (in pseudo-code, because I avoid Perl like the plague):

```
list linkNames;
count = selenium.get_xpath_count('//li/a');
for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
   list.append(selenium.get_text('xpath=(//li/a)[' + i +']');
}
```

Note:

- XPath expressions count from 1 to n, not 0 to n-1 like most C-derived languages.
- The XPath form for selecting the i'th match of a pattern is `(pattern)[i]`, not `pattern[i]`.
- Selenium  doesn't assume the `(pattern)[i]` locator is an XPath, so you need say so by starting it with `xpath=`.